# how can I use a CGPoint value from one method in another within the same class

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Sorry if this sounds quite simple. I am new to Cocos2d and Obj-C. I want to compare the CGPoint value of a sprite in one method with a value caluculated in another method. How can I access this value from one method to another within the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass it into the method or declare a private property to hold the value:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint myCGPoint;
```

And then synthesize it in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize myCGPoint;
```